# Distinct and order by for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, row-number

This is my query result;

[image: query result]

I am trying use distinct and multiple order by. Maybe I could not tell. But my firstly order by parameter is "priority1" column and secondly order by parameter is "point" With Distinct Sid. So;

The most important column for me is "priorty1"

The second most important column "Point"
but every "sid" will be displayed once.

What I want ?

- I want Id is 7 because priorty1 is maximum, among the ones with ID 1509.
- I want Id is 9 because Point is maximum, among the ones with ID 1510.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, you could use `Row_number` function to assign ranking or Row_orders to your result set:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,
           [Sid],
           [Point],
           [priority1],
           JoinDate,
           Title,
           Content,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Sid] ORDER BY [priority1] desc, [Point] desc) AS RN
    FROM <your_resultset>
) a where a.RN = 1;
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Helped a lot today.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cte and `row_number` to get your desired result as below.

```
 WITH cte as
  (SELECT t1.*, ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY sid
                                  ORDER BY priority DESC, point DESC) AS rn
   FROM table1 t1)
SELECT id,
       sid,
       point,
       priority --- and other columns
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

**Result:**

```
id  sid     point   priority
---------------------------
7   1509    10      3
9   1510    45      2
```

You can check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/FOJM24664)**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Sid,
       MAX(Point) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY (priority1, Point)) as top_point,
       MAX(priority1) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY (priority1, Point)) as top_priority,
       ....
FROM (The query you have)
GROUP By Sid
```

Read more here
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/analysis.htm#DWHSG0205

By distinct I guess you mean just one value so it's base of grouping.

UPDATE

From
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql

```
SELECT
  Sid, priority1, Point,
  row_number() over(partition by Sid order by priority1, Point) as roworder
FROM (the query) 
HAVING roworder=1 ;
```

Comment: Can i use "Dense_Rank" in Mssql ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql but could be my syntax is wrong for SQL Server

Comment: Yes, your syntax is wrong. Do you have another idea ?

Comment: One more attempt to express)